# How to make radio button in ajax - php?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, radio-button

What's wrong with the code of radio button?
When I've tried SELECT/OPTION it's working.

I'm trying to make two groups of radio button, get their values and sum up.
but I can't move through since the radio buttons don't make response at all.

These are inputs to my form:

```
<input type='radio' id='1' name='r' onclick='pieces('this.value')' 
       autocomplete='off' value='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' id='2' name='r' onclick='pieces('this.value')' 
       autocomplete='off' value='no'>No
```

**My script:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function pieces(str)
    { 

        if (str=='')
        {
            document.getElementById(abc).innerHTML='';
            return;
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById(abc).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET','price.php?q='+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified script. 
Inputs:

```
<input type='radio' id='1' name='r' onclick="pieces(this.value);" 
       autocomplete='off' value='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' id='2' name='r' onclick="pieces(this.value);" 
       autocomplete='off' value='no'>No
```

Here is the js script:

```
 function pieces(str)
    { 

        if (str=='')
          {
          document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML='Choose something';
          return;
          }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
              }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

        xmlhttp.open('GET','hey.php?q='+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Let me know if any prob.

Jasminder

Comment: thanks it works... hope you could answer my follow up question :)

Comment: If this works, up-vote and mark @jasminder answer as correct.  Ask a new question and don't post a follow-up question as an answer.